# centrar vertical y horizontalmente con posición fija un elemento cuando hay 2 columnas css

Tags: html, css, css-grid-layout

Quiero crear una plantilla donde pueda tener 2 columnas y en la primera columna pueda fijar vertical y horizontalmente su contenido de acuerdo al tamaño de su sección con posición fija y en la segunda con flujo de acuerdo a su largo sin desbordar hacia la otra columna. Si hay contenido extra como el `footer`, mi clase **navigation** invade el espacio de éste ¿es posible que se quede a la mitad del tamaño del elemento lista?

En este código si la pantalla se reduce, la columna lista invade el espacio de la columna **navigation**, es por la regla de la clase centra **position: fixed**.

Mi código `html`

```css
body {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-column: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-row: repeat(1, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "t s";
}

.navigation {
  grid-area: t;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.centrar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.lista {
  grid-area: s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class='centrar'>
      <label>Seleccione color</label>
      <select class="">
        <option value="rojo">rojo</option>
        <option value="verde">verde</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <label>Seleccione un número</label>
      <select class="">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <label>Seleccione una letra</label>
      <select class="">
        <option value="2">A</option>
        <option value="3">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="lista">
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
    <p>Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1Hola1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenías varios errores en tu código CSS en 2 propiedades que querías llamar, estas eran `grid-template-column` y `grid-template-row` te faltaba escribir una s al final de ellas, lo correcto es `grid-template-columns` y `grid-template-rows`. En cuanto al diseño que querías pude llegar a la solución utilizando Flexbox, ya que si lo único que necesitas son 2 columnas fácilmente se puede hacer con Flexbox, con CSS Grid es para plantillas un poco más complicadas, con más secciones.

Otro error que tenías en tu CSS era que estabas aplicando la propiedad de `fixed` en el div incorrecto, esto debería de haber sido en el contenedor (`.navigation` ) y no en el elemento (`.centrar`) . Apliqué un fondo de color blanco pero puedes quitarlo ya que el elemento con la clase de  `.lista` le apliqué un margen encima cuando el navegador tenga una resolución menor a 1024px.

Otro problema estaba en tu HTML, tenías "className" para asignar una clase de `.lista` pero lo correcto es escribir siempre "class", "className" no existe.

Me encarguè de hacer el diseño responsivo, para cuando la pantalla del navegador alcanze al menos 1024px, que es lo "normal", tendrás una columna centrada con tu menú del lado izquierdo y por el lado derecho tendrás tu contenido que tomará todo el espacio que le quede a la pantalla. Cuando la resolución de la pantalla sea menor que 1024px tendrás un diseño de tipo columna, esto hará que tu menú se vea fijado por encima de tu contenido y este será fijado.

main.css

```
body {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
  
  .wrapper {
/*     display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); */
/*     grid-template-rows: repeat(1, auto); */
/*     grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-areas: "t s"; */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .navigation {
/*     grid-area: t; */
/*     padding-left: 15px; */
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
  }
  
  .centrar {
    /* position: fixed; */
    top: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
/*     z-index: 3; */
  }
  
  .lista {
/*     grid-area: s; */
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 144px;
  }

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .navigation {
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
    }
    .lista {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="navigation">

          <div class='centrar'>

            <label>Seleccione color</label>
            <select class="">
              <option value="rojo">rojo</option>
              <option value="verde">verde</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            
            <label>Seleccione un número</label>
            <select class="">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <br/>

            <label>Seleccione una letra</label>
            <select class="">
              <option value="2">A</option>
              <option value="3">B</option>
            </select>

          </div> <!-- nav items end -->

        </div> <!-- nav end -->
      
        <div class="lista">
          <p> Este es el principio de mi bloque de texto. 
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque facilis porro ullam quaerat libero non tempore voluptas, eveniet modi perspiciatis. Quod velit asperiores corporis fugiat est recusandae quisquam deserunt totam quas quibusdam reprehenderit minus corrupti, facere, excepturi amet consequatur, explicabo enim iste eveniet vero dolor quia! Dolorem sapiente exercitationem officiis dolorum temporibus reprehenderit blanditiis ea, magnam sunt cupiditate alias optio quibusdam id perferendis atque voluptatibus similique eius, sed eligendi saepe laborum impedit! Iste velit quidem libero asperiores quia maiores aspernatur reprehenderit, veniam fugiat necessitatibus tenetur voluptatibus quo porro perferendis sunt deserunt officiis temporibus inventore cumque ratione. Quas facere est expedita, consectetur sed esse sunt iure animi ut ex culpa modi repellendus assumenda dignissimos repudiandae quae neque accusamus. Dolorum consequuntur cupiditate, veritatis itaque molestiae nostrum nisi id molestias delectus et eveniet consequatur quas repudiandae quos ex, inventore voluptatum possimus. Earum debitis doloremque quia eaque reiciendis tempora, dolorem minima, doloribus nobis quaerat, iusto omnis ratione. In, aut. Porro quam pariatur, dolor in ipsum, quod cumque recusandae aspernatur optio rerum accusantium totam, harum consectetur. Rem, magnam accusamus consectetur tempora eum odit ipsum sunt beatae ab nesciunt. Magnam, totam quod soluta facere delectus quaerat eum consectetur esse error ipsam asperiores fugiat, sunt officiis fugit corporis dolore mollitia officia ut ratione. Fugiat, fuga! Vitae eius alias odio optio voluptatibus officia porro tenetur? Dicta, qui similique sunt officiis rem possimus alias exercitationem voluptates quisquam, inventore beatae odit deleniti ipsum expedita temporibus iste vitae, ratione quam quasi voluptatibus fugiat! Explicabo blanditiis consectetur iste inventore nostrum quam? Sequi quasi ad sed eos perferendis recusandae laborum porro nisi esse voluptas dolores, cumque nemo ducimus vel molestias assumenda corporis aperiam ipsum libero quos minus voluptatum facilis mollitia? Facilis corporis placeat praesentium repellat eos deserunt quaerat error fugiat incidunt sint quia nobis, ducimus sequi enim recusandae modi alias at, repudiandae expedita.

          </p>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- wrapper end -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: interesante, manda hacia arriba caundo la pantalla es más pequeña, pero como se haría si quiero que siempre quede a 50 % de tamaño de pantalla en el eje "y" y solo haya scroll en la parte del texto

Comment: Si quieres que la parte de arriba tenga un alto de 50%, cambia el valor de la propiedad de height en la clase .navigation (creo esa era) y ponle 50%, puedes usar píxeles también, por ejemplo 200px. Si esta respuesta te fue útil te pido que la aceptes como respuesta, si necesitas otra cosa abre otra pregunta, saludos.

Comment: que quede a mitad del largo de pantalla fija en el eje y, del tamaño no importa, quiero que esos select siempre estén a la vista, con respecto a pantallas pequeñas, en tamaños pequeño y cel, lo voy a ocultar